# Cruise control merging problem

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, nant

I am using cruise control which generated a  particular output
which is in text file format.So with the help of nant i am copying
this file to another .xml of the same name in some other folder
structure and i am using the file merge task which merges this output
with my log files.I am also able to see this output merged in my
webdashboard.Now i want this same output i.e .xml to be attached in
may mail too.So is there anyway i can get this done??At present i dont
get anything attached in my mail i.e no errors or warnings attached.

Thanks and regards
Maddy

Answer (score 0):

From what you say, i think you need to modify your `ccnet.exe.config`  This contains the section (near the top by default called `xslFiles` which specify what XSL is used to transform the log for the email publisher.

All you should need to do is add another line with the path to whatever your translation is:

```
<xslFiles>
  <file name="xsl\header.xsl"/>
  <file name="xsl\compile.xsl"/>
  <file name="xsl\modifications.xsl"/>
  <file name="xsl\BuildSummary.xsl" />
  <file name="xsl\your_xsl_file_path.xsl" /> <!--Here-->
</xslFiles>
```

Comment: Hi andy,I had done as u had told and i am getting an error in the command prompt window of the ccnet .The first part of error is shown below:------------
Unable to build email message: ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.CruiseControlException: Unable to load transform: xsl\Critical_error.xsl ---> System.Xml.Xsl.XslLoadException: XSLT compile error. An error occurred at C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\xsl\Critical_error.xsl(1,1). --->

Can u please tell me what could be the problem?

Comment: without being able to see your XSL - not easily.  I would guess at having some invalid XSL in that file

Comment: Andy,I am actuall getting the output as .txt file.I jst copy that file to another file of the same name with .xsl extension.So is there anything i need to do to convert any txt file to xsl file or jst the extension tyoe change is enough?please correct me if i am wrong
Regards
Maddy

Comment: Ah, once you have use the Merge task in your ccnet.config file, you no longer need the text file.  What you do need is an XSL file that will transform that output into something that goes in the email.  If you mean adding the .txt file as an attachment, im not sure you can.

Comment: So u mean that i can only merge file which are having the xsl format?
So now is there anyway where i can merge my output with my mail??
I m really trying very hard to get it.